# Insert variable into sqlite data base table

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

I can't insert data into sqlite table.
Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('mydata.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
a=raw_input('name')
a=str(a)
b=raw_input('theme')
b=str(b)
c=raw_input('language')
c=str(c)
sql="INSERT INTO Website (Website, Theme, Language) VALUES (%, %, %)",(a,b,c)
cursor.execute(sql)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

For some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the extended call syntax is `f(*args)`:

  ```
  cursor.execute(*sql)
  ```
- sqlite uses `'?'` placeholder:

  ```
  conn.execute('insert into sometable values (?,?,?)', (a,b,c))
  ```
- `raw_input()` already returns a string. `a = str(a)` is unnecessary

Comment: thanks I tried your code and I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\Soso\Desktop\projetpython\database    \insert_variables.py", line 13, in <module>
       cursor.execute(sql)
       ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode

Comment: @user1119429: [update](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9350129/edit) your question and add full traceback and the code that you've tried.